# How to output exact values that contain every <div> and <span> with same id

Tags: javascript, html

I want to output full message when someone on chat(YouTube) writes it, but I can not sort it from spans, it just checking only first div and span.
for example:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("one");
var keyword = "Hi!";
var search = document.getElementById("message").textContent;
var a = document.getElementById("elem");
a.addEventListener('click', msg, false)

function msg() {
  for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
    if (search.includes('Hi!')) {
      alert(search)
    } else {
      alert("nope")
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <span id="message">Hi!</span>
</div>
<div id="one">
  <span id="message">Goodbye!</span>
</div>
<div id="one">
  <span id="message">Hi!</span>
</div>
<div id="button">
  <input type="button" value="press on me" id="elem">
</div>
```

I think, firstly, I need to use classes, but I just dont understand how to do it with classes, and secondly, it must be dynamicly.

Comment: document.getElementById("one") will get you exactly one element. Do you want to go through all child elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you do wrong?

- `addEventListener` function directly instead of use `() =>{function}`
- Use multiple ids, **must be unique**, instead i used `data-attribute`
- Try to use `if (search.includes('Hi!')) {` (search is an array like div), instead i select directly all text and use `forEach` for compare each one.

```js
const keyword = "Hi!";
const a = document.getElementById("elem");
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
  msg();
}, false)

function msg() {
  const search = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-one] > span[data-message]");
  search.forEach(term => {
    if (term.textContent.includes(keyword)) {
      console.log(term.textContent);
    } else {
      console.log('no match');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div data-one>
  <span data-message>Hi!</span>
</div>
<div data-one>
  <span data-message>Goodbye!</span>
</div>
<div data-one>
  <span data-message>Hi! odoisjiosjojsojo</span>
</div>
<div id="button">
  <input type="button" value="press on me" id="elem">
</div>
```

PS: remember to change `const` into `let` if you need to rewrite it.

Comment: Yea, it kinda works, but I mean, I need to output full msg, like if its inlcude keyword, it must show full message

Comment: You search keyword "Hi!" with what assumption the script will show full message? And which is the full message? If you mean full text, i changed `keyword` with `term.textContent`

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, its completly fine now